# How to delete lines starting with certain numbers in a file?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, line

Simple question here but I'm kinda stuck.

Let's say I have a file with 20 lines and 4 columns. The first column is a number (1 to 20).

I have an other file with a few numbers in it like this

```
1
4
19
```

Now, how can I delete the line (in the first file) starting with the numbers in the second file. My main problem is that if I do a sed, the number 1 will get 10, 11, 12, and on. How can I do this the right way?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: examples

file1

```
1       a       a       a
2       b       b       b
3       c       c       c
4       d       d       d
5       e       e       e
6       f       f       f
7       g       g       g
8       h       h       h
9       i       i       i
10      j       j       j
11      k       k       k
12      l       l       l
13      m       m       m
14      n       n       n
15      o       o       o
16      p       p       p
17      q       q       q
18      r       r       r
19      s       s       s
20      t       t       t
```

file2

```
1
4
19
```

the result I want:

```
2       b       b       b
3       c       c       c
5       e       e       e
6       f       f       f
7       g       g       g
8       h       h       h
9       i       i       i
10      j       j       j
11      k       k       k
12      l       l       l
13      m       m       m
14      n       n       n
15      o       o       o
16      p       p       p
17      q       q       q
18      r       r       r
20      t       t       t
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]; next} !($1 in a)' file2 file1
2       b       b       b
3       c       c       c
5       e       e       e
6       f       f       f
7       g       g       g
8       h       h       h
9       i       i       i
10      j       j       j
11      k       k       k
12      l       l       l
13      m       m       m
14      n       n       n
15      o       o       o
16      p       p       p
17      q       q       q
18      r       r       r
20      t       t       t
```

**Breakup of awk command**:

```
FNR == NR {                  # While processing the file2
  a[$1]                      # store the 1st field in an array
  next                       # move to next record
}
                             # while processing the file1
!($1 in a)                   # print a row from file1 if 1st field is not in array 'a'
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I'm not sure I understand how this is supposed to work though... I'm not comfortable with awk just yet. I'll do some research and try some code!

Comment: If you provide a sample of input data from 2 files in question then I can update the answer with more details.

Comment: I edited my original post! My first comment was simply because I do not understand all the details about awk yet.

Comment: You can always ask for more help if something is not clear. I've added details about awk command used. I'd also suggest reading a good tutorial on awk. It is much simpler than `sed` and may I add more efficient too for cases like this.

Comment: Thank you! I just tried it again and it works like a charm. Also your explanation really helped me understand how to use the command!

Answer (score 4):

You can use sed to create a sed script that deletes the given lines:

```
 sed 's=^=/^=;s=$=\\s/d=' numbers
```

It creates the following sed script:

```
/^1\s/d
/^4\s/d
/^19\s/d
```

I.e. delete the line if it starts with a 1, 4, or 19, followed by whitespace.

You can directly pipe it to sed to run it:

```
sed 's=^=/^=;s=$=\\s/d=' numbers | sed -f- input-file
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks a lot! I'll have to study sed a little more because I do not understand this line perfectly 's=^=/^=;s=$=\\s/d=' but at least I know I can do it!

Comment: @Yarmiz: It just puts `/^` at the beginning, and `\s/d` at the end of every line.